# 2014 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Theoretical Computer Science's [second moderator election](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the two new moderators are:

[image: Lev Reyzin] [image: Artem Kaznatcheev]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5451934982995968/0).

Note that [Dave Clarke](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/77/dave-clarke) and [Kaveh](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/186/kaveh) will be stepping down after helping the newly-elected moderators learn the tools and processes. They've both donated a considerable amount of their time and expertise to keeping this community operating smoothly - please show them your appreciation for a job well done!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Excellent news.

Comment: Thank you! And thanks to Dave and Kaveh (and of course Suresh) for their great work these couple years.  I'm hoping to get to learn from them how to do this job :)

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Thank you! I am looking forward to learning the ropes, and I am sad to see Dave and Kaveh go, you guys have done a great job!

Comment: Thanks to Dave and Kaveh, too; they made a great work here!

Comment: hi all CONGRATS & here is some [geekish nate silveresque analysis/commentary of election results](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13463207#13463207), whether there is any upset, how it would have been predicted by rep, how it relates to offsite activity to this site [eg blogging/publicity], and how it relates to meta activity/engagement on the site. think the election has been worthwhile exercise for a "level set" & injecting some new energy/directions into the site. ***THANK YOU VERY MUCH TO MY SUPPORTERS. NOW THE PARKING BRAKE IS OFF THIS THING! STICK AROUND & STAY TUNED!***